# How to update SQL Server table with sum of 3 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Simply I have table called `ForecastTotal`, I want to sum 3 columns which may have null values and put the result in `TotalAchievementVol`

For example

**ForecastTotal**:

```
    OVERSEASVol  UCPVol        IBNSINAVol 
    -------------------------------------
    1              3             4
    1              2             1
    2              null          3
    3              1             null
```

I used this query

```
Update ForecastTotal 
Set TotalAchievementVol = (SUM(ISNULL(OVERSEASVol, 0)) + 
                           SUM(ISNULL(UCPVol, 0)) + 
                           SUM(ISNULL(IBNSINAVol, 0)))
```

but I get an error

> Msg 157, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
>   An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.

Any help?

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you want `sum()`.  It is an aggregation function that adds values across multiple rows.  You just want to add values within a row, so the appropriate method is simply `+`:

```
Update ForecastTotal
    set TotalAcheivmentVol = COALESCE(OVERSEASVol, 0)) + COALESCE(UCPVol, 0)) + COALESCE(IBNSINAVol, 0);
```

Note:  I prefer the ANSI standard `COALESCE()` to `ISNULL()`.

However, I would not implement this functionality using an actual column.  Just use a computed column:

```
alter table ForecastTotal
    add TotalAcheivmentVol as ( COALESCE(OVERSEASVol, 0)) + COALESCE(UCPVol, 0)) + COALESCE(IBNSINAVol, 0) );
```

The values are calculated when you query the table, so they are always up-to-date.

Comment: Sum will take all the values of a given column regardless the row you are updating.